# Kendo Ui web Listview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Listview of kendo ui. I have no server wrapper class I am using the free web version.
My controller code is given below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }



public ActionResult GetCandidateSearch()
        {
            IhrmsEntities Entity = new IhrmsEntities();
            List<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH> lstCandidateSearch = Entity.VW_CANDBASICSEARCH.Take(50).ToList();
            return Json(lstCandidateSearch,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My index.cshtml

```
<div>
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/PvCandidateBasicSearch.cshtml")
</div>
```

My PvCandidateBasicSearch.cshtml

```
<div class="gridHolder" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="listCandidateView" class="itemDisplay"></div>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="itemDisplay">
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_NAME} </div>
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_LOCATION} </div>
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_MOBILE} </div>
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_PRE_EMAIL} </div>
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_SKILL} </div>
        <div class="text-label">${CAND_CITY} </div>
        <a href="/Home/EditCandidate?id=${CAND_ID}" >Edit</a>
       <a href="/Home/DeleteCandidate?id=${CAND_ID}" >Delete</a>
    </div>
</script>






<style type="text/css">
    .text-label {
        font-size: large;
    }



 .itemDisplay {
 margin: auto;
 padding: 6px 8px;
 width:auto;
 min-width:200px;
 height: auto;
 min-height:100px;
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background: #deefff;
}

    .gridHolder{width: 100%; height:auto; min-height:300px; margin:auto;}
</style>
```

My javascript code in layout.cshtml is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Home/GetCandidateSearch',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"

            }
        },
        pageSize: 15

    });

    $("#pager").kendoPager({

        dataSource: dataSource
    });

    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {


        LoadListView();

    });
    function LoadListView() {


        $("#listCandidateView").kendoListView({

            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
        });


    }


</script>
```

**when I first click search button it is perfectly going to the GetCandidateSearch action method and showing result.But when I second time clicking  search button it is not going the action method. Plz help me.**

Comment: did the below help? if so, please make it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the the datasource concept.

The datasource is an object holds the data gathered from request.  On the second click you just re-binding that datasource to the ListView...

Basically, you need to bind the list view to the datasource on page load, then "OnClick", do `datasource.read()`

try this:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/Home/GetCandidateSearch',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"

        }
    },
    pageSize: 15

});
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#listCandidateView").kendoListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
    });
});


$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    $("#listCandidateView").datasource.read();
});
```

Not saying that the exact code will work, but it should give you an idea of the approach.